# triangle of square numbers java

Tags: java, loops, recursion

So i'll be as specific as I can here. My lab requires a java console app where the user can enter any number between 1 and 9. The computer will then print a triangle of each number squared, and the triangle has to be aligned on the right side of the screen. Here is the example:

```
          1
       4  1
    9  4  1
16  9  4  1.
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9 inclusive:");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=n; i++) {
            for (int j = n-i; j >=1; j--) {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
            for (int k = i; k <=i; k++ ) {
                System.out.print("    " + i * i);
            }
            System.out.println("    "); 
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my output:

```
         1
       4  
    9  
16
```

My problem here is that I can repeat each number on each line and fully fill the triangle, but I cant figure out how to print the sqrt of each previous count without writing a million nested loops.
Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the second inner loop needs to be adjusted a little bit (changes in **bold**):

```
for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--) {
    System.out.printf("  %2d", k * k);
}
```

The first inner loop for indention runs `n-i` times, so the second inner loop have to do the rest: `i..1`.

And you have to print the square of the inner loop variable `k` instead of the outer loop variable `i` (which does not change in the inner loop).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the loop limits for the second loop

```
        for (int k = i; k <=i; k++ ) {
```

You initialize **k** to **i**, and then stop the loop when **k > i**.  This can execute only once under a "standard" increment.  You need to run **k** to the end of the line:

```
        for (int k = i; k <=n; k++ ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to adjust and add a few more increment variable before the outer loop, and in the outer loop as well to subtract from the overall count and increment for each cycle of the inner loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9 inclusive:");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int num = 0, temp = 0;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <=n; i++) {
        int l = 0;
        num++;
        temp = num * num;
           for (int j = n-i; j >=1; j--) {
            System.out.print("   ");
           }
           for (int k = 1; k <=i; k++ ) {


            System.out.print("  " + temp);

            l++;
            temp = i -l;
            temp = (int)Math.pow(temp, 2);

                       }

           System.out.println("  "); 

    }






    }

}
```